# Using python regular expressions to sub between two files

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

Basically I'm trying to read text from a text file, use a regular expression to sub it into something else and then write it to a html file.

here's a snippet of what i have:

```
from re import sub

def markup():
    ##sub code here
    sub('[a-z]+', 'test', file_contents)
```

the problem seems to be with that sub line.
The below code (part of the same function) needs to make a html file with the subbed text.

```
    ## write the HTML file
    opfile = open(output_file, 'w') 
    opfile.write('<html>\n')    
    opfile.write('<head>\n') 
    opfile.write('<title>') 
    opfile.write(file_title) 
    opfile.write('</title>\n') 
    opfile.write('</head>\n') 
    opfile.write('<body>\n')
    opfile.write(file_contents)
    opfile.write('</body>\n')
    opfile.write('</html>')
    opfile.close()
```

the function here is designed so i can take text out of multiple files. after calling the markup function i can copy everything after file_contents except for the stuff in brackets, which i would replace with the names of the other files.

```
def content_func():
    global file_contents
    global file_title
    global output_file
    file_contents = open('example.txt', 'U').read()
    file_title = ('example')
    output_file = ('example.html')
    markup()

content_func()
```

Example.txt is just a text file containing the text "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog". what i'm hoping to achieve is to search text for specific markup language and replace it with HTML markup, but I've simplified it here to help me try and figure it out.

running this code should theoretically create a html file called example.html with a title and text saying "test", however this is not the case. i'm not familiar with regular expressions and they are driving me crazy. can anyone please suggest what i should do with the regular expression 'sub'?

**EDIT:** the code doesn't produce any errors, but the output HTML file lacks any substituted text. so the sub is searching the external text file but isn't putting it into the output HTML file.

Comment: Can you provide the full code? Don't you get any errors? Also why `open` has "U" as mode (I am also new to python and have never seen it)

Comment: This basically is the full code minus some repeated lines and values at the end.

i don't get any errors from the script - i probably should have mentioned that - but the output html file doesn't have the subbed text in it. i think i'll add that in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never save the result of `sub()`. Replace

```
sub('[a-z]+', 'test', file_contents)
```

with this

```
file_contents = sub('[a-z]+', 'test', file_contents)
```

Comment: thank you! i was just thinking of doing something like this, it's just what i need.